# Declaring Variables Outside of Functions

Tags: javascript, function, variables

What kind of variables can be declared outside of functions in JavaScript? I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the following code.

This code doesn't affect `subtitle`.

```
var element = window.document.getElementById("subtitle");
var test = "Changed!";

function check(){
    element.innerHTML = test;
}
```

However, if I move `element` inside the function, then the `subtitle` element changes to "Changed!".

```
var test = "Changed!";

function check()
{
    var element = window.document.getElementById("subtitle");
    element.innerHTML = test;
}
```

Is there a rule that says `window` objects can't be  assigned to `var` outside of a function, is there a mistaken in the code, or am I just not understanding JavaScript variables?

Comment: When you say that it "works as intended", do you mean that the code loads up properly or that when you execute the function it does what you expect?

Comment: Variables can be declared anywhere. If your first example "does not work" then there might be an error somewhere, but it is not in the code you posted. The problem is probably what jeff explains in his answer.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the post. "Works as intended" means that the text inside of the `subtitle` element becomes "Changed!".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables can contain any data type. The first shown code is likely not working because  the document isn't loaded when you fetch the value for `element`, while the second code is working because the document is loaded by the time `check()` is called.

If you want to use global variables, try this:

```
var element;
var test = "Changed!";

window.onload = function() {
    element = window.document.getElementById("subtitle");
    check();
}
```

Comment: Yes! `document` isn't loaded yet, of course. Thank you, I understand now. So, only after `window` has been loaded, we can begin to call elements in `document`.